# What does it mean for $AA^T$ to be symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetry

What does it mean for $AA^T$ to be symmetric?

A question in my book says to show that $AA^T$ is symmetric so I took a very simple matrix to try and understand this:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 8
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$
$A^T=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 8
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

$AA^T=\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 16 \\ 16 & 64
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

But I don't understand how this is symmetric.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=symmetric+matrix Come on...

Comment: @nik I'm studying right out of a school text book and I had a question.  That's what this place is for, no?  Sometimes the book isn't very clear and other people can explain it better.

Comment: Yes, this place is for questions, but usually a modicum of research is expected from people who ask questions. You don't have to use your book and MSE as your only sources of information.

Comment: In any case looking up "symmetric matrix" on google would have given you the same answers as here.

Comment: I think it seems obvious to you what one should google because you're familiar with the subject.  This a brand new subject to me and understanding what you need to research is paramount to being able to conduct effective research.

Comment: Hi, any feedback on my answer would be nice...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 16 \\ 16 & 64
 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

is symmetric because it equals its own transpose:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 16 \\ 16 & 64
 \\ \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 16 \\ 16 & 64
 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Isn't that the definition of "symmetric"?

Comment: I know what symmetric means, I just didn't understand it in these terms.  In any case, your comment really drove the point home, "it equals it own transpose."  That made it crystal clear.  Thank you

Answer (score 8):

A matrix $A$ is symmetric if $A^T=A$ and notice that this can happen only for square matrix. Moreover we can easily see that
$$(A^T)^T=A\qquad;\qquad(AB)^T=B^TA^T$$

Now in your case since we have
$$(AA^T)^T=(A^T)^T A^T=AA^T$$ 
hence the matrix $AA^T$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 6):

A square matrix $B$ is called *symmetric* if $B^T = B$. In other words, the $(i,j)$-th entry is the same as the $(j,i)$-th entry which indeed is the case with the matrix that you obtain.

Comment: In other words, the matrix is symmetric with respect to the main diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

$(AA^{T})^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T$
So, $AA^T$is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

For vectors $A$ you can write $AA^T$ using the superoperator notation as follows:
$$
\rm{ vec} AA^T= A^*\otimes A,
$$
where $\otimes$ deontes the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). 
If we now look at the matrix repesentation of the Transposition superoperator
$$
\hat T = \pmatrix{1 &0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1}
$$
we recognize the [bit reversal operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation) (this holds for dimensions of $A$ equal to a power of $2$, as far as I remember). $\hat T$ applied on $X\otimes Y$ gives:
$$
\hat T (X\otimes Y) = Y \otimes X
$$

So the fact that $AA^T$ is symmetric, means that $\rm{ vec} AA^T$ is a eigenvector (with eigenvalue $+1$) of the transposition superoperator.